# PHP 7 - Comparing Anonymous Class Instances

Tags: php, php-7, anonymous-class

I have tried this code:

```
$ac1 = new class {};
$ac2 = new class {};

var_dump($ac1); // object(class@anonymous)#1 (0) {}
var_dump($ac2); // object(class@anonymous)#2 (0) {}
var_dump(new class {}); // object(class@anonymous)#3 (0) {}

var_dump($ac1 == $ac2); // bool(false)
var_dump($ac1 == new class {}); // bool(false)
var_dump($ac2 == new class {}); // bool(false)
```

The result of the above comparisons are all **false**.

However, when I declare a function that returns an anonymous class, this is the result:

```
function anonymous_class() {
    return new class {};
}

$ac1 = anonymous_class();
$ac2 = anonymous_class();

var_dump($ac1); // object(class@anonymous)#1 (0) {}
var_dump($ac2); // object(class@anonymous)#2 (0) {}
var_dump(anonymous_class()); // object(class@anonymous)#3 (0) {}

var_dump($ac1 == $ac2); // bool(true)
var_dump($ac1 == anonymous_class()); // bool(true)
var_dump($ac2 == anonymous_class()); // bool(true)
```

All printed **true**.

Now, the question is, how did that happen? Particularly, why did it print **true** for the second context, knowing that each `var_dump()` of the instances resulted differently?

Comment: As a fast and loose answer: in your first sample you have three different "physical" `class` declarations, which become three different classes. In the second sample, you have only one `class`, and three instances of it.

Comment: @deceze You gave a good summary. Why not make it an answer?

Comment: @chumkiu already did a good job of that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From doc http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.anonymous.php

> All objects created by the same anonymous class declaration are instances of that very class.

```
<?php
function anonymous_class()
{
    return new class {};
}

if (get_class(anonymous_class()) === get_class(anonymous_class())) {
    echo 'same class';
} else {
    echo 'different class';
}
```

> The above example will output: same class

And from http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.object-comparison.php

> When using the comparison operator `==`, object variables are compared in a simple manner, namely: Two object instances are equal if they have the same attributes and values (values are compared with ==), and are instances of the same class.

Comment: Yes I've read that, but check the `var_dump()` output of each instance, they are different.

Comment: @Rax The `#1` after the class name is the *instance counter* (first instance of `class@anonymous`). The class name is identical in all cases.

Comment: Combining your answer and @deceze's gives me a clear view of it. Awesome.